# JPA: Why is ID of selected object null?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my JPA application, I am using the following SELECT statement to retrieve a user from the database:

```
TypedQuery<AppAdmin> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM AppAdmin a WHERE a.username=:username", AppAdmin.class);
query.setParameter("username", username);
AppAdmin user = query.getSingleResult();
```

However, the user's id field is always null, even though I checked that the field is not null in the database. What could be the cause of this behaviour?

The following shows my `AppAdmin` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "u_userdetails_admin")
public class AppAdmin extends BasicUser {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -41356272870596876L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    protected AppAdmin(){}

    public AppAdmin(
            @JsonProperty("id") UUID id, 
            @JsonProperty("username") String username,
            @JsonProperty("password") String password, 
            @JsonProperty("registrationDate") LocalDate registrationDate,
            @JsonProperty("locked") boolean locked, 
            @JsonProperty("enabled") boolean enabled,
            @JsonProperty("activationKey") String activationKey,
            @JsonProperty("email") String email) {
        super(id, username, password, registrationDate, locked, enabled, activationKey, email, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should precise the dbms used and the id column type. It may have incidence.

Comment: The dbms used is MySQL, the id column type binary(16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem: `AppAdmin` extends `BasicUser` and I defined an id field in both classes. The inheritance strategy is set to `InheritanceType.JOINED`, and removing the id defintion in `AppAdmin` causes the IDs to be loaded again. However, I am not sure if this is the real cause of the problem, as it used to work before until it just stopped working at some point.